# Connecting to MongoDB using PyMongo on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I have created an account with Atlas and now I am trying to retrieve some information from the database. My native language is R, so I inserted the "iris" data set into the collection called "table".
To show that there is data in my new database "test", I use the mongolite command (this is the R pymongo):

```
#m is my client connection
m$count()
[1]5490
```

The problem is connecting with python. I am currently on Jupyter Notebook. Here is the code.

```
import pymongo as pm
import pprint
import requests

url= "mongodb://jordan:*************@jordandb-shard-00-00-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017,jordandb-shard-00-01-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017,jordandb-shard-00-02-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=JordanDB-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true"

client = pm.MongoClient(url)
print(client)
[out]Database(MongoClient(host=['jordandb-shard-00-02-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017', 'jordandb-shard-00-01-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017', 'jordandb-shard-00-00-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, ssl=True, replicaset='JordanDB-shard-0', authsource='admin', retrywrites=True), 'test')
#I am assuming this means I am connected
```

When I call any methods on the database I get the error.

```
db = client.test #test is name of collection
db.iris.find_one({})

ServerSelectionTimeoutError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-ab74ef5f0195> in <module>()
----> 1 db.iris.find_one({})

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in find_one(self, filter, *args, **kwargs)
   1260 
   1261         cursor = self.find(filter, *args, **kwargs)
-> 1262         for result in cursor.limit(-1):
   1263             return result
   1264         return None
```

I would like to be able to connect and start exploring the data in my "test" data set by using methods like, list_database_names(), list_collection_names() etc.. Thank you kindly

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?? beacuse im also facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I am using a python kernel in a jupyter notebook though but the logic remains the same

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
# replace "USER" and "PASSWORD" with your user and password respectively.
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@cluster0-hhhbr.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

# replace "local" with any database in your cluster
db = client.local
# replace "emps" with your collection's name
collection = db.emps

# you can use the collection e.g, but this will return a cursor
collection.find()

# To get the actual data do this or create a context
# Don't forget to delete the 3 previous lines of codes if you are going to
# create a context
with client as cl:
    db = cl.local
    collection = db.emps
    for i in collection.find():
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

**To connect to mongodb using python from any editor**

import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/") 
mydb = myclient["pyramids"]  **#pyramids is the database**
mycol = mydb["invoices"]  **#invoice is the collection**